# Order of Bosses - Terraria

Tags: terraria

I’ve been trying to kill a bunch of bosses for a while now but most of the time, I’ve looked up the best weapons for the jobs and they say to use things that I can only obtain after fighting another boss. Is there a good way to go abour defeating these guys, or should I just choose one and go for it with a normal weapon?

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to Terraria!

If you're playing on a PC, the usual order goes like this:

1. King Slime (Spawned with Slime Crown
2. Eye of Cthulhu (spawned with a Suspicious-Looking Eye)
3. Eater of Worlds/Brain of Cthulhu (spawned by breaking Shadow Orbs or Crimson Hearts)
4. Skeletron (spawned at the Dungeon entrance)
5. The Wall of Flesh (summoned with a Guide Voodoo doll)
6. The Mech Bosses (you can look these up on the wiki, but I recommend fighting the Destroyer first)
7. Plantera
8. Golem
9. Duke Fishron
10. The Lunatic Cultist
11. The Moon Lord

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The game is designed in a way that defeating bosses generally unlocks new crafting materials, which you can use to craft better weapons (and use that to defeat stronger bosses). And the developer don't explicitly prevent you from having access to very strong weapons that you "shouldn't have at the moment" (because it's too overpowered).

Obviously if you use an end-game weapon like the [S.D.M.G.](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/S.D.M.G.) or [Phantasm](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Phantasm) to defeat early-game bosses like [Eye of Cthulhu](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Eye_of_Cthulhu), it would be extremely easy but it would quickly get boring.

The point is for you to craft the best weapon **available at the moment** and keep crafting better weapons and equipment as you kill stronger bosses and progress through the game.

Comment: This addresses nothing about what the OP needs to know.

Comment: @TheMattbat999 if you had bothered reading the actual question content, you would realize that he is 'looking for a good way to go about defeating these guys' and not actually 'the order of bosses'

Comment: My bad bro. Albiet the question title and description do not match.